# SignalR implementation using Swift 3.0

Tags: swift, signalr, cocoapods, swiftr

I am trying to implement SignalR using SwiftR.connect - I followed this [tutorial](https://github.com/adamhartford/SwiftR/tree/swift23).

Getting Following Error.

> ```
>  Starting...
>  Error: Optional(["message": Error during negotiation request.]) 
>  Disconnected.
> ```

My source code

```
import UIKit
import SwiftR

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var statusLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var startButton: UIButton!

    var chatHub: Hub!
    var connection: SignalR!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        SwiftR.useWKWebView = true

        SwiftR.signalRVersion = .v2_2_1
        SwiftR.transport = .longPolling          

        connection = SwiftR.connect("http://192.168.X.XX/MyChatApplicationServer/signalr") { [weak self] connection in

            self?.chatHub = connection.createHubProxy("MyChatHub")
            self?.chatHub?.on("newMessageReceived") { args in
                print("MyChatHub on call start")

                let message = args![0] as! String
                let detail = args![1] as! String

                print("Message: \(message) \nDetail: \(detail)")

            }

            // SignalR events
            connection.starting = { [weak self] in
                self?.statusLabel.text = "Starting..."
                self?.startButton.isEnabled = false
                print("Starting....")
            }

            connection.reconnecting = { [weak self] in
                self?.statusLabel.text = "Reconnecting..."
                self?.startButton.isEnabled = false
                print("Reconnecting....")
            }

            connection.connected = { [weak self] in
                print("Connection ID: \(connection.connectionID!)")
                self?.statusLabel.text = "Connected"
                self?.startButton.isEnabled = true
                self?.startButton.setTitle("Stop", for: .normal)
                print("Connected")
            }

            connection.reconnected = { [weak self] in
                self?.statusLabel.text = "Reconnected. Connection ID: \(connection.connectionID!)"
                self?.startButton.isEnabled = true
                self?.startButton.setTitle("Stop", for: .normal)
                print("Stop")
            }

            connection.disconnected = { [weak self] in
                self?.statusLabel.text = "Disconnected"
                self?.startButton.isEnabled = true
                self?.startButton.setTitle("Start", for: .normal)
                print("Disconnected")
            }

            connection.connectionSlow = { print("Connection slow...") }

            connection.error = { error in
                print("Error: \(error)")

                // Here's an example of how to automatically reconnect after a timeout.
                //
                // For example, on the device, if the app is in the background long enough
                // for the SignalR connection to time out, you'll get disconnected/error
                // notifications when the app becomes active again.

                if let source = error?["source"] as? String, source == "TimeoutException" {
                    print("Connection timed out. Restarting...")
                    connection.start()
                }
            }

            connection.start()
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func startStop(_ sender: Any) {

        if let text = startButton.titleLabel?.text{
            print("text val: \(text)")
            connection?.start()
        }else{
            connection?.stop()
        }
    }

}
```

Note: 
1) I had updated SignalR **Installation** using **pod 'SwiftR'**
2) As per the tutorial i am using **swift23 branch code**
3) In **pod SwiftR library** following code not working.

> connection =
>   SigmalR("http://192.168.X.XX/MyChatApplicationServer/signalr")

Getting Following Error.

```
"Cannot invoke initializer for type 'SignalR' with an argument list of type '(String)'"
```

If i am **following master branch code.**

Please help me with this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The pod (swift3), the swift23 branch, and the master branch (API changes) are all different code. You'll need to pick one version of the library and stick with it. If WKWebView = false works, but true doesn't, that means you probably don't have  CORS enabled on your SignalR server.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this issue](https://github.com/adamhartford/SwiftR/issues/75) on the rep you used.

I advice to think about [ObjC implementation.](https://github.com/DyKnow/SignalR-ObjC) Since it is just pod, nothing bad with it.

Comment: Thanks for reply but i got the solution and now its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Just commented following code and it's working fine.
//SwiftR.useWKWebView = true

Answer (score 0):

This issue already discussed in GitHub. Check here https://github.com/adamhartford/SwiftR/issues/75

Does it work with SwiftR.useWKWebView = false?

If so, make sure you have CORS enabled on your server. CORS is required for WKWebView to work with SwiftR.